# Convergence of the sum of i.i.d samples

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem, law-of-large-numbers

Say $x_i, i=1,2,3,\dots$ are i.i.d random variable. Let $S_n=\sum_{i=1}^nx_i$. We know from the law of large numbers that
\begin{align}
\frac{S_n}{n}\rightarrow E[x_1]
\end{align}
We also know if $var(x_1)<\infty$ that the convergence rate is $1/\sqrt{n}$.

Is it possible to say something about the convergence of $S_n$? Suppose $x_1$ has all moments finite. Can we say that $S_n\rightarrow nE[x_1]$? If not, why? Also it does not converge, can we add some more condition on the distribution of $x_1$ to make $S_n$ converge?

Comment: $S_n$ itself diverges almost surely, except in the trivial case where $x_i$ are identically zero.  This is a good exercise in Borel-Cantelli.

Comment: The statement $S_n \to n E[x_1]$ doesn't make sense; you can't have $n$ on the right side of a limit statement.  You could ask about something like $S_n \sim n E[x_1]$ but that's just a restatement of the law of large numbers you just gave.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you say a little bit more about $S_n\sim nE[x_1]$. Does the statement mean that their ratio goes to $1$ as $n$ goes to $\infty$?

Comment: Correct, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis#Definition.  This is the usual way of expressing the informal statement "$S_n$ is about as large as $n E[x_1]$ as $n$ becomes large", and that's how the large of large numbers is usually interpreted.